# setting content-disposition for docx using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Iam trying to add `Content-Disposition` to my docx files in s3. Something along the lines of: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.docx"`. I want to do this because IE (< 9) downloads docx files as zip files. After some googling I found that there is a workaround for this, by adding a `content-disposition` to the content as well. I tried using the  `before_post_process` call back and did

```
before_post_process :set_content_disposition

def set_content_disposition
  filename = self.attachment.instance.attachment_file_name
  self.attachment.instance_write(:content_disposition, "attachment; filename="+filename) 
end
```

But, it still downloads as zip file. Is there a way to correctly do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a way .. there is a **before_post_process** callback with paperclip gem.

we can do something like this..

```
has_attached_file :sample
before_post_process :set_content_dispositon

def set_content_dispositon
  self.sample.options.merge({:s3_headers => {"Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename="+self.sample_file_name}})
end
```

Comment: this should be `.merge!`

Answer (score 9):

Prozac's answer (using before_post_process to edit the options) didn't work for me. However, there's now a simpler method, anyway. You can pass a proc directly to the :s3_headers key in the options hash of your has_attached_file call:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, {
  ...,
  :s3_headers => lambda { |attachment|
    # pass whatever you want in place of "attachment.name"
    { "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=\"#{attachment.name}\"" }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, very small comment, there's always a way to avoid escaping in ruby, here for example even if you already had `'`, you could still use `%(attachment; filename="#{attachment.name}")`

Comment: It seems in recent Paperclip this proc runs before attachment is populated. ```{"id":null,"document_file_name":null,"document_content_type":null,"document_file_size":null,"document_updated_at":null,"solution_id":null,"user_id":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}``` Any idea how to get attachment details once set so I can dynamically set Content-Disposition?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with paperclip but the correct **MIME Type/Content Type** for `docx` files is **`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`**.

Using that will stop IE downloading them as zip files.

Here are all the MIME types for the new office formats.

```
Extension   MIME Type
.xlsx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.xltx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
.potx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
.ppsx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
.pptx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.sldx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide
.docx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.xlam   application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
.xlsb   application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
```

Comment: Check out my answer.. the soln you mentioned is when we serve the files from our server.

Comment: I'm glad you have a working solution but you still still be using the correct `Content-Type` for files stored and served from S3.

Answer (score 0):

Prozac,

I think that in Paperclip you have to set s3_header['Content-Disposition'] hash but I'm in the same issue given that s3_header hash is not interpolated I still can't figure out how to put the filename there without patch Paperclip

check this solution http://groups.google.com/group/paperclip-plugin/browse_thread/thread/bff66a0672a3159b

Comment: great find prozac, but I have a slightly different scenario, I have a custom processor, I was trying to implement what you respond here but I couldn't because seems that before_post_process doesn't run if you have a custom processor. Do you have idea how to do it together with a custom processor?